# Laravel Dynamic Dependent Dropdown Menu

Tags: ajax, laravel, dynamic, dropdown

I would like to be able to select a vehicle type and use the price associated with that selection to add it to the base price of the services in the cards. I know there are many examples to change the options in a second drop-down menu, the classic country and state example, but I can't seem to find anything that uses the selected menu item in a way where I can add it to the service price. Here is the code I have so far:

```xml
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Select vehicle type
     </button>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
         @foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ $vehicle->type }}</a>
         @endforeach
     </div>
</div>
</div>
@foreach($services as $service)
    <div class="card mt-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{ $service->nom }}</h4>
                {{--this is where I'd like to use the selected vehicle type to simply add it to 
                the service price. If i do: {{ $service->price + $vehicle->price }} it chooses 
                the last one that went through the foreach loop --}}
                <h3>{{ $service->price }}$</h3>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text">{{ $service->description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I'm aware this is not very fancy (or good) programming but I've been stuck on this for hours. I also know I'll need a script to make it actually dynamic and most probably use form to select the vehicle type.

Comment: So basically [tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs)?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script> 
  function updateServicePrice(vehicle) {
    const vehiclePrice = Number(vehicle.dataset.price);
    const services = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('service-price'));
    
    services.forEach(service => {
      service.innerHTML = Number(service.dataset.price) + vehiclePrice;
    });
  } 
</script>


<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Select vehicle type
     </button>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
         @foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
             <a onclick="updateServicePrice(this)" data-price="{{ $vehicle->price }}" class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ $vehicle->type }}</a>
         @endforeach
     </div>
</div>
</div>
@foreach($services as $service)
    <div class="card mt-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{ $service->nom }}</h4>
                {{--this is where I'd like to use the selected vehicle type to simply add it to 
                the service price. If i do: {{ $service->price + $vehicle->price }} it chooses 
                the last one that went through the foreach loop --}}
                <h3 class="service-price" data-price="{{ $service->price }}">{{ $service->price }}$</h3>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text">{{ $service->description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know you could do it that way. You're a life saver!

Comment: Do you know why it's not working when trying with a select in order to show the selection from the dropdown menu on the button?

Comment: When your Larael code produces result, you have no any selected vehicle, thus you can't calculate price, therefore you need to listen for vehicle selection and update price.
if you want do all the work without using script in client side then you should submit your selected vehicle by using `a` or `form` and construct new page with calculated price using Laravel's template engine